# How to find answers which use code snippets?

Tags: support, search, stack-snippets

How can I find a list of answers which use code snippets?

If I want to find answers having a code block for a specific tag, I can find it with the following search query: 
[**code:true is:a [C#]**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code%3Atrue+is%3Aa+%5BC%23%5D)

Is there any way to find answers which use code snippets?

For example: if I want to check the Angular answers with code samples in code snippets. So I can simply run the code, without creating any fiddle.

The code snippet is not specific to Stack Overflow; it is available on other Stack Exchange sites too, therefore I'm posting here.

Comment: Can you state the purpose behind seeking such answers?

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, _find the answers having the code block for a specific tag_. For an example I want to check the angular tagged answers with code samples in the code snippets only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snippets are rendered as follows:

```
<div class="snippet" ...
```

It's hard (impossible?) to search for this via the UI (or the API) since those elements are probably not even indexed. So we turn to SEDE for help; a LIKE on post body is expensive, and even if I filter on the [angular] tag, I have to specify a date limit as well. But in the end it should work. Feel free to fork [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1070416/posts-containing-snippets-by-tag?tagName=angular) to tune it to your needs.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1070413?tagname=angular) that let you do that as there is no mean to achieve what you ask with the on-site search.

```sql
;with lastmarkdown as
(
select max(id) phid
      , postid
 from posthistory
 where posthistorytypeid in (2,4,8)
 group by postid
)

select top 100 
       a.id as [Post Link]
     , body
     , text
from posts a
inner join lastmarkdown ld on a.id = ld.postid 
inner join posthistory ph on ld.phid = ph.id
inner join posttags pt on a.parentid = pt.postid
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
where t.tagname = ##tagname:string?angular##
and a.score > 0
and text like '%<!-- begin snippet:%<!-- end snippet -->%'
```

I use the fact that the markdown text will contain `<!-- begin snippet:` and `<!-- end snippet -->` when a snippet is present. It is a bit harder to find the latest markdown but with Common Table Expression to return the highest Id of body edits in the PostHistory table and joining later with PostHistory to get the actual markdown does the trick. Markdown is more likely to be stable while the element and classes in the generated HTML can change when an SE developer sees fit.

The LIKE clause will give headaches for large resultsets  so make sure the table scan is on a reasonable scoped subset. Here I only included positive scoring answers and topped the resultset at 100 rows.

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday.

Comment: Thanks for your time and query.